# Save time like TimeSpan and parse it

Tags: c#, devexpress, xpo, xaf

I using xaf and xpo for my app.
I have TimeSpan field for time:

```
private TimeSpan showTime;

public TimeSpan ShowTime
{
    get { return showTime; }
    set { SetPropertyValue("ShowTime", ref showTime, value); }
}
```

In the DB it saves like `float`.
In the app(generated by DevExpress) the time shows normally: `22:00:00`, in the table like:`79200`
In another project I load data from this column and I can't parse it.

```
<li><a href="#"><%=TimeSpan.Parse(schedule.ShowTime.Value.ToString()) %></a></li>
```

I have got: `79200.00:00:00`

How to parse properly?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `schedule.ShowTime.Value` is of type *double* which is the amount of seconds, you need to use FromSeconds method:

```
<%=TimeSpan.FromSeconds(schedule.ShowTime.Value) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a solution to allow a user to enter TimeSpan as Text and save it as it's a time span. 
Take a look http://mdworkstuff.blogspot.com/2011/03/timespan-editor-for-xaf.html